# Does an SD card have an internal controller

Tags: partitioning, sd-card, mbr, gpt, dd

I'm still confused as to how a host computer (Windows or Linux) communicates with an SD card.

When we completely reformat and clear an SD card (for example using the Linux dd utility), does this completely clear the entire contents of the card? If that's the case, if we re-partition the card again, where is this partitioning information stored?

I would guess that there is an MBR or GPT partition table stored at a part on the card that can't be overwritten, the same as a hard disk, but i'm not sure.

Answer (score 3):

An SD card is a block device like a hard drive, SSD or USB drive.

From the OS/host perspective, if you use dd on the raw drive it will be overwritten - MBR and all (just like a hard drive).

If you repartition the SD card it writes the partition information to the beginning if the card - same as a hard drive. You can reformat the partition with any appropriate filesystem (under Linux this includes ext filesystems among others)

There are a couple of things to clarify:

- It is trivial to overwrite the GPT/MBR on hard disks.
- While, in practice dd'ing a disk will fully wipe it (and if run over the whole disk will wipe it from the OS perspective), it is possible the drive will have some bad/hidden sectors which are not actually zeroed - this probably only matters if you have super sensitive data on the drive and want to wipe it and give it to someone else.  The same is true of HDD's and to an even greater extent SSDs which have significant areas hidden from the OS to extend the disks usable life - Google SSD over-provisioning)

Answer (score 1):

An SD card is a hard disk for all intents and purposes.

Most SD cards ship preformatted with one or more MBR partitions, where the first
or only partition contains a file system, just like a hard disk.

Per the SD card size, it is formatted with MBR and a file system which would
normally be FAT12/16/32.

Every part of the card can be overwritten. If you destroy the partition table,
you would need to write a new one.

See [Wikipedia SD card](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SD_card).

Comment: I'm confused by a case where a card is completely wiped, then re-partitioned into multiple partitions, but without an MBR present. Linux is still somehow able to understand all the partitions using the fdisk -l command

Comment: If you re-partitioned it then you have created an MBR. A partition table is required to contain partition data.

Comment: @engineer999 When there are parititions there is always an MBR present, as the partitions are defined as part of the MBR.   (A GPT will have an MBR which shows the entire disk as in use).  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record#Disk_partitioning - Have a look aat the "Structure of a classic MBR" which shows the disk layout (The "Modern standard structure" is  more complex version of this - in both cases the partitions start at +446 decimal - which is the key bit